# CSS: Properly limit size of two images in a table

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, image-resizing

I have a simple HTML/CSS task. I have a page with two images of the same size displayed in a row. See [this page](https://octonus.graphicon.ru/GMLePublish/HDRTools/Public/sample.htm). I need to adjust displayed size of the images to meet *all* of these criteria:

1. Images must be fully visible together in the browser's window, i.e. size of containig div/table is limitied to the size of client area
2. Images are not enlarged, aspect ratio is preserved
3. Images are centered horizontally with constant space between them
4. Works at least in IE9, Chrome and Safari

I'm not very experienced in CSS, so I can beat up at most 2 criterion of 4.

The sample page I'm currently using satisfy 3, 4 and partially 1 (only width is restricted). I leaved sample as close to my problem as possible, leaving in all related master CSS files and automatically generated ASP.NET containters.

Images should remain in `input` tag, not in `img`, it's desirable, though not crucial. Would you please suggest a proper combinatoin of style attributes satisfying all the conditions?

**Update:**

Solution with relaxed criterion 1, where images are allowed to have height more than client area's height, would be appreciated too.

Comment: is it required that you keep using a table to contain images?

Comment: @GionaF No. I just thought it would come in handy.

Comment: I've created chat room for this question: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17237/css-properly-limit-size-of-two-images-in-a-table

Comment: Sorry, i've tried but i can't either preserve the ratio or fit in the height ;-)

Comment: @GionaF Even more, I bet you didn't check it in more than one browser :)

Comment: You're wrong ;-) check my answer

Comment: @GionaF I did and posted a comment. I just saw your demos, didn't try the solution for my page yet. I assume the tool you used to share the demos is trustworthy.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, but i used images as background instead of `<img>`. Hope it's not an issue.

With `background-size:contain;` the background image is scaled, while preserving the image’s original proportions / aspect ratio. It is supported by FF4+, IE9+, Chrome1+ (with vendor prefix), Opera10+ and Safari 3+ ([source](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/)).

---

The main problem with your first requirement: "size of containig div/table is limitied to the size of client area", is that you can't set `height:100%;` unless the parent container has an height set too.

In your page i see that you've an header and a footer with dynamic height, so you'll need some jQuery to adjust the container's height. But let's first see how to do it with just CSS, then we'll add an header and footer.

---

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/uuFNb/)** (try to resize the window)

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="body">
    <div>
        <div class="left"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#body, #body > div {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#body > div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; /* or whatever you need */
}
#body > div > div {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top center;
    -webkit-background-size:contain; /* Chrome1+, Safari 3+ */
    background-size:contain; /* FF4+, IE9+, Chrome3+, Opera10+, Safari 3+ */
}
#body > div > div.left {
    background-image:url(/* your left image url */);
    max-width:417px; /* the real image width */
    max-height:512px;; /* the real image height */
}
#body > div > div.right {
    background-image:url(/* your right image url */);
    max-width:417px; /* the real image width */
    max-height:512px;; /* the real image height */
}​
```

---

Let's add the header and footer. We have to remove `height:100%;` from #body, and calculate its height as a result of: window height - header height - footer height.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Dx3VG/)** (resize the window)

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<header>I'm a header</header>
<div id="body">
    <div>
        <div class="left"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>I'm a footer</footer>
</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
header, footer {
    background:grey;
}
#body {
    height:400px; /* fallback no javascript */
}
#body, #body > div {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#body > div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:10px; /* or whatever you need */
}
#body > div > div {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top center;
    -webkit-background-size:contain; /* Chrome1+, Safari 3+ */
    background-size:contain; /* FF4+, IE9+, Chrome3+, Opera10+, Safari 3+ */
}
#body > div > div.left {
    background-image:url(/* your left image url */);
    max-width:417px; /* the real image width */
    max-height:512px;; /* the real image height */
}
#body > div > div.right {
    background-image:url(/* your right image url */);
    max-width:417px; /* the real image width */
    max-height:512px;; /* the real image height */
}​
```

jQuery:

```
function calcHeight(){
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var headHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
    var footHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();
    var bodyHeight =  docHeight - ( headHeight + footHeight);
    $('#body').height(bodyHeight);
}
calcHeight(); /* called first time on page load */
$(window).on('resize',calcHeight());​/* do the math again when window's resized */
```

I think it's pretty straight forward. I wrote it this way to make it understandable, but of course you can compress it more.

I've used `outerHeight` for footer and header to include possible margins.

If you don't want to include the jQuery library, there's surely a pure JavaScript way to obtain the same.

Comment: In your first sample criterion 3 is violated - space between images is not constant. In the second sample image height is ignored and footer is not rendered beneath the images. If possible, I would prefer a less strict solution (see update in the question), but without JavaScript and BG images.

Comment: @Mikhail **it is** constant. Well, good luck for the rest, i already know how to do it with your new requirements, but i hate when the "rules" change after i brained for a solution.

Comment: It is not constant, when you set small window height. At least in Chrome. Check this screentshot: http://postimage.org/image/8sxeqfwol/

Comment: @Mikhail What you mean by constant? How can it be constant with images **centered horizontally**?

Comment: Two images with constant space between them represents a block, which is centered horizontally.

Comment: @Mikhail In your screenshot there's a ratio horizontal/vertical like 6 to 1, something that will never happen in real life. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

In order to maintain the aspect ratio only define width in css, it will automatically adjust the height to maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not an answer.